# Excel Index Match with If Criteria

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula

I have 2 excel workbooks like so:

Workbook1

```
A (Delivery Date)     B  (Item Code)        C (Expected Delivery quantity)     D (Received Stock)  
01/11/2016            412                   100                        0
31/10/2016            234                   200                        200
02/11/2016            111                   10                         6
```

Workbook 2

```
A (Item Code)        B (Status)
412                  Delivery expected 01/11/2016
234                  Delivered
111                  Insufficient Stock Delivered
```

I am trying to run an excel formula in column B of workbook2 which will update the user on the status of deliveries where the item code matches.

Workbook 1 gives an expected delivery date for each item in column A, and an expected quantity of delivered items in COlumn C.

I want to create an If formula to put in column B in workbook 2, which will check if the expected quantity for each item (column C) matches the received stock in column D.

If the received stock is more or matches the expected delivery quantity, i want the status to say 'Delivered'.

If the received stock is less than the expected delivery quantity then i want the status to say Insufficient Stock delivered.

If the received stock is 0, i want the status to say 'Delivery Expected' and to pull through the delivery date from column A. So you would get 'Delivery Expected 01/11/2016'.

So far i am trying to put together an if statement like so:

```
=IF('[workbook1.xlsm]Sheet1'!$D$1:$D$10000=0,"Delivery Due"&Index('[workbook1.xlsm]Sheet1'!$A$1:$A$10000',Match(B1,'[workbook1.xlsm]Sheet1'!$B$1:$B$10000),0),IF('[workbook1.xlsm]Sheet1'!$D$1:$D$10000<'[workbook1.xlsm]Sheet1'!$C$1:$C$10000,"Insufficient Stock Deliverd","Delivered")
```

My formula does not work and i get a #Value Error. please can someone show me where i am going wrong and how i can achieve my final result?

Comment: You need to look up relevant values for each item in WB2 for which you would use VLOOKUP. If it is possible to add a formula in WB1, I suggest you add the status in Col E. And then in Workbook 2 to look up the status using VLOOKUP.

Comment: @eshwar thanks for your idea but it is not possible to make any amendments to WB1

Comment: then you will need separate VLOOKUPs to get Expected & Received. Use those in the if statement like you have

Comment: But your IF will be for values in current row alone.

Answer (score 0):

It's a quite long formula.

```
=IF(INDEX([WorkBook1.xlsm]Sheet1!A:D,MATCH(A2,[WorkBook1.xlsm]Sheet1!B:B,0),3)=INDEX([WorkBook1.xlsm]Sheet1!A:D,MATCH(A2,[WorkBook1.xlsm]Sheet1!B:B,0),4),"Delivered",IF(0=INDEX([WorkBook1.xlsm]Sheet1!A:D,MATCH(A2,[WorkBook1.xlsm]Sheet1!B:B,0),4),CONCATENATE("Delivery Expected ",TEXT(INDEX([WorkBook1.xlsm]Sheet1!A:D,MATCH(A2,[WorkBook1.xlsm]Sheet1!B:B,0),1),"DD/MM/YYYY")),IF(INDEX([WorkBook1.xlsm]Sheet1!A:D,MATCH(A2,[WorkBook1.xlsm]Sheet1!B:B,0),3)>INDEX([WorkBook1.xlsm]Sheet1!A:D,MATCH(A2,[WorkBook1.xlsm]Sheet1!B:B,0),4),"Insufficient Stock Delivered",)))
```

Go to name manager and assign this formula to any name like "Status"

and all the cells from B2 to B1000 will have only ***`=status`*** as formula.

Let me know if it works.